# Emulating Curl --user --insecure in c#

Tags: c#, curl, webrequest

I have the following Curl Call that works.

```
curl --insecure --user user@applicationname:password "https://someURL"
```

I cannot for the life of me get HttpWebRequest to emulate this.

Currently I am trying

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someURL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " +    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER@Account:Password"));
```

I am getting the error Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

I am guessing it has to do with the curl command having the insecure option but I cannot for the life of me see how to do this in the request.

Do to network restrictions/policies I cannot download restSharp or any other 3rd party libraries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before doing the request

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, X509certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: @Contristo can you provide the URL, so I can reproduce the error

Comment: I can't it's internal sorry. It is hitting an App Dynamics server. Was trying to use their rest API.

Comment: @Contristo if you put a breackpoint inside this lambda, when you make request, it stop on breackpoint?

Comment: It does,  does not crash till I do a getResponse.

Comment: @Contristo what the exception that you get?

Comment: @Contristo you must try to change this value `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;` You can also try the other values of this enum.

Comment: First off, thank you for taking so much time to help me on this issue. That last line of code is now making the exception a 400 bad request error.

Previously it was a "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Comment: @Contristo If you do same request with curl the return is 400?

Comment: the curl command I have up top returns the expected data. Just for fun I changed my password in c# to be wrong and it changed the error to be a 401 unauthorized. I feel like we are very close.

Comment: @Contristo can you see the responde body of the Bad Request response?

Comment: I have switched to using HttpClient am and now getting the proper response. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Contristo can you answer your own question? So people can try what you did :D

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and posted the full solution but credited you with the answer, I still had to use the code you provided to get this to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @Contristo thanks, I am really happy that its working now. If you have any other question I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using HttpClient instead. In combination with using the info obtained from @Alberto Monteiro above, I was able to get the my code to work as expected.

```
        string url = Request.Form["Url"];

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
             ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

             ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, x509Certificate, chain, errors) => true;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Request.Form["User"] + "@ACCOUNT:" + Request.Form["Pass"]);
            var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        }
```